# Where we can use AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

**Is it worthwhile to learn AS3 and what are the uses of this awesome programming language we have left in our hands?**

```
I'm just curious to know about the fact that is it still worthwhile? 
My focus is only to create visualizations etc.
And for that purpose we get another language "Processing" so where we are now?
```

Your valuable comments will be highly beneficial for me. Thanks.

Comment: You can learn [HaXe](http://haxe.org/) which is very similar to AS3, but has a lot of extra features and targets and at the moment, by the looks of it more future proof. There are similarities between AS3/Java/C# from the syntax point of view. In a simplified form Processing is a Java library. You can use C# in Unity for example which is easy to pick up and awesome at 3D visualisation. I've been coding in as3 for about 10 years so the question wether it's still worthwhile will get you a very subjective view from me. A language is just a tool: it's more important what you want to do with it...

Comment: ...what drives you, what gets you enthusiastic ? This will make the learning process easy and enjoyable, even when it's hard. Also, once you learn and get used to one language, you can always pick up another later on (it's much easier). I guess it also depends on how much time you give yourself to learn, do you want to make a living out of this or just have fun (there is no right or wrong), etc.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents.

I'm a senior as3 developer. I loved it, it was the programming language that introduced me to OOP and programming best practices. I still believe it is an awesome tool, with a great syntax and with some great prototyping capabilities.

Is it worthing to learn it now? I don't believe so, unfortunately.

If you already know it it's a great tool to control, but investing your time to learn it could not be such a good idea. As everything, it will keep some time to get used to it and to control it. And it that time you could be learning something that is going to be on the scene longer.

I have few clients that keep asking for projects done in as3. I'm still using it to do AIR desktop apps or prototype for big clients, but again, I use it because I already knew it.
Meanwhile I switched to Processing for interactive installations (even if sometimes I still use as3 for them), Objective-c for mobile development, and some JS stuff for other things.

Obviously it depends what are you aiming for. I've shared my thoughts as an Interaction Designer / Interactive Developer freelancer.

Comment: I'm a software engineer working with java and databases nowadays for some business applications. My eternal wish is to become an artist who create artistry with code. And AS3 was the first thing I aware of at that times. I did few tidbits but really don't know the deep of this language. Alas! I'm a confused person and never get my hands dirty in the mix of this tool. To be very honest I'm a guy who driven by the circumstances. I don't follow my dream. And that's why I'm not an interactive developer. To be an interactive developer who can create pretty visualizations and stuff is my interest.

Comment: @Superman if those are your interested, and you know java, I would definitely work in processing :) Again, keep in mind that I love as3 more than processing, but the Adobe's plan for the future are really unclear, and I would not be surprise if they will drop it completely. Meanwhile the guys from processing are doing an excellent work in keeping the language on

Comment: @Sr.Richie - Is this the [Processing](http://www.processing.org/) you're talking about?

Comment: @greetification yes it is

Answer (score 1):

> Is it worthwhile to learn AS3

It really depends on the specificity of your project. Specifically if you are building for the web, and need a flexible language that can handle a lot of video processing consistently across multiple platforms, then Flash with ActionScript 3 might be right tool for the job. Flash has been a web standard for some time. HTML5 also has a lot of these capabilities and surpassing Flash in some respects, although it's highly inconsistent still across mobile devices.

---

> My focus is only to create visualizations etc

If you are working with 3D graphics, AS3 with APIs like Stage3D are definitely going to be a good way to go. Again, this is geared towards web development only. Although flash is fine on mobile as a standalone, alternative languages especially native ones have proven to perform better.

---

I am  currently a Senior level ActionScript 3 Game Developer. I have been working with ActionScript 3 as well as HTML5 coupled with JavaScript to develop these applications. In my experience ActionScript 3 is great to learn if you want to get something off the ground quickly. It does not have a steep learning curve, and has plenty of room to learn the ins and outs of Object orientated programming, design patterns, development techniques and best practices etc. So I'll list some of the advantages and disadvantages I've discovered.

**The pros to learning ActionScript 3 are:**

- Easy to learn, Object Orientated Programming Language
- Plenty of tutorials, information, polished frameworks to pull from ( Box2D, Starling, Stage3D )
- Active helpful community, lots of support
- Dynamic and flexible language
- Portable to multiple platforms
- Still a front running web standard (installed on most machines) with great web services

**The cons:**

- Interpreted language. (Code execution is less efficient, has to be interpreted at runtime and/or interpreted to intermediary language before execution)
- **Overall restrictive performance**. I put this in bold as this is a constant limitation you are developing against when working with Flash. Even in highly optimized projects, I feel there is more a struggle with Flash than other languages and frameworks. You can hit some real limitations when it comes to graphics processing on a large scale even with Stage3D, Starling, and well rounded blitting techniques.
- Dynamic Language. Yes I listed this as a pro, but it is also a con. Dynamic languages make development time faster by sidestepping type conversion, but they also can create conversion errors that would have normally been caught during compile time in a strict type language.

These are just some of the pros and cons to flash, tied in with some of my opinions and experience. In short, it's a great language to learn if you are just starting out and want to get something on the screen fast and particularly for the web. Outside of that you'll find more power and capabilities from other languages/frameworks suited for graphics rendering.

Comment: Thanks Bennett for your time and effort to put in altogether for me. It gives me confidence to stick with AS3 and do something creative, at least a wonderful website for myself? :) Thanks.

Comment: An example of what kind of things impressed me a lot. 

http://thibaud.be/

Comment: Very well done website, and also a good example of the pros and cons to using Flash. On large resolutions for example, the performance of that flash application can look a little jarring, but scaled down the app runs very well.

Comment: @Superman this kind of website can now be scripted in html/css/js

Answer (score 0):

People mostly program web video players, flash games, ADs and mobile/tablet games with them. It is good for one who want to go indie.
But if you want to program mobile games or desktop games, then I'd suggest C# instead. This is really opinion based.

From my point of view, the flash game market is dropped, as one of the biggest support site (`Mochi`) leaves the market, and the newcomers, the newbies sell their games way cheaper than a pro who knows how much it really worths.
I've been programming games in `AS3` in a while, but I'm moving on C# with frameworks such as `MonoGame` and with the `Box2D` physics engine port to `C#`, `FarseerPhysics`, to develop more efficient desktop and mobile applications.